# MySql, Engine Memory, index needed for this simple table?

Tags: mysql, heap-memory

I'm trying to implement a very fast table meant to store relationships between users.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends_ram` (
`a` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`b` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO friends_ram (a, b)
```

I made some tests with circa 5M of relations and it's blazing fast and it occupies circa 134MB of ram; my question is, since the queries will be:

```
SELECT a WHERE b = 'foo';
```

or

```
SELECT b WHERE a = 'baar';
```

I'd like to know if I should use a proper indexing (increasing the size of RAM required).

Comment: Only way to tell is by adding the index, see what the memory usage is, and see what the performance difference is. 2x memory usage (making up some numbers) for 10% better performance wouldn't be worth it in my book, but 2x memory for 10x speed = good.

Comment: apparently it's another 61MB for the two indexes, I'll make some test with microtime and see what's the gain. but with only two decimals from mysql CLI it's clear it's even faster. I'll post results later.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually ashamed of the results,

Probably the first time I made the tests i misread the output.

Turns out that with 1000 random queries without index on `a` or `b` it takes 1000 the times with proper indexing. ahem...

Another very important thing to notice is that I tried with memcached. while it takes a little longer to store data it's faster for retrieval. also it consumes way less memory.

```
mysql 192MB -> Mysql MEMORY engine did it in; 0.50138092041016 seconds
memcached  76MB -> Memcache engine did it in; 0.34592795372009 seconds
memcached compressed: 45.4 MBytes -> Memcache engine did it in; 0.31583189964294 seconds
```

so, if you need to store simple things such as these I'd recommend memcached (compressed)